# Haskell - Couldn't match type

Tags: string, haskell, floating-point

I am trying to write a function in Haskell that takes as input a String and a list with the pattern [(String, Float)] and output the Float assigned to the key String that matches my input, but I don't understand what am I doing wrong.
This is my code:

```
a = [("x",1.21),("y",3.52),("z",6.72)]

val :: String -> [(String, Float)] -> Float
val x [(s,f)]
 | x == s    = f
```

And it gives me the error

```
* Couldn't match type `Double' with `Float'
  Expected type: [(String, Float)]
    Actual type: [([Char], Double)]
* In the second argument of `val', namely `a'
  In the expression: val "x" a
  In an equation for `it': it = val "x" a
```

Could anyone explain what am I doing wrong and how does this type mismatch make sense?

Comment: Did you define a `String` type yourself?

Comment: wait, you need to do that?

Comment: no, I'm trying to debug the problem. A `String` is an alias for `[Char]`. So it looks like your `String` is not the builtin `String` type.

Comment: Are you sure first line of the error mesage is not `Couldn't match type 'Double' with 'Float'`

Comment: @boran no, it said first about the string

Comment: Well, that's certainly not what any recent GHC does. I think you just made a mistake re-typing the error message, always better to copy&paste.

Comment: I'm voting to close, because this code does not cause the error in the question. If you want help, we need a minimal reproducing example, emphasis on reproducing.

Comment: It is impossible for us to debug this without a minimal code which actually reproduces the issue. The posted code, alone, does not cause the posted error. Try copying your file into a new one, and remove stuff from it as much as possible while preserving the error, then post that.

Comment: Type explicitly `a` : `a :: [(String, Float)]`

Comment: @Damien worked, but now I get that non-exhaustive patterns error, is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in the definition of `val`, not in the type signature:

1. the guard options are not exhaustive: what happens when x is not equal to s?
2. the `[(s,f)]` part is not a pattern for a list: you would regularly use a variable name, or a pattern.
3. What happens if after traversing the whole list you don't find a match? Do you throw an error, or a Maybe, or return a sensible default value?

Consider this solution throwing an error:``

```
val :: String -> [(String, Float)] -> Float
val x [] = error ("Not Found: " ++ show x)    
val x ((s,f):rest)  | s==x = f
                    | otherwise = val x rest
```

You could also return `Just f` and `Nothing` if you use Maybes.